# Using the ternary operator multiple times

Tags: javascript

I am currently doing some coding challenges and encountered one which I wanted to solve with using the ternary operator.
I know that there is some previous answers but no one (that I found) was using the ternary operator.
Do you know what did I miss here?

The point here is to add 1 to a if a1>b1, 1 to b if b1 > a1 etc. ...
One other point is, if a1 = b1, no one gets a point
Link to the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets/problem

```js
function compareTriplets(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2) {
  let dataCompilator = [0, 0]
  a0 > b0 ? dataCompilator[0] += 1 : dataCompilator[1] += 1;
  a1 > b1 ? dataCompilator[0] += 1 : dataCompilator[1] += 1;
  a2 > b2 ? dataCompilator[0] += 1 : dataCompilator[1] += 1;
  return dataCompilator;
}
console.log(compareTriplets(5, 6, 7, 3, 6, 10))
```

My output:
0 3

What the output SHOULD have been:
1 1

Comment: Well, they don't call it a challenge for nothing.

Comment: How did you call this function? I have a feeling you sent in an (unexpected) array.

Comment: I can't agree more to what you just said, but besides that, my real will is to know which part of my ternary operator i screwed up, since i really want to have a better pov on it, the challenge is optionnal :) @tadman

Comment: The output will never be `1 1` since it's not sum of `3`

Comment: It was called later on on the program with the following input :
const result = compareTriplets(a, b);
@tadman

Comment: Oops, forgot some informations on this one, let me edit it real quick, sorry for it.

Comment: Edited the code , the output does not matches with your output

Comment: A ternary operator returns whatever the result is. You're returning dataCompilator[0] += 1 without doing anything with it

Comment: The ternary operator should evaluate to a value that is then used (in an assignment, a function call, ...) and not do "magic" in its if and else parts.

Comment: Don't forget the case when the values are the same and no increment should happen!

Comment: Thanks @brk ! It's way more readable now, will keep this level of proposing code in the future :)

Comment: The issue is that you never check if the values are equal. Right now you add to b if the values are equal

Comment: But shouldn't the array upgrade itself while adding a value to the array ? I will look further into it, thanks @niorad

Comment: This function, as defined, takes 6 arguments. If you're calling it like `c([5,6,7],[3,6,10])` that's wrong, you need them *all* expressed as arguments, not grouped into arrays, or you need to re-write the function to be `f(a,b)` and then `a[0]` vs. `a0` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have three cases:

- `a > b`: `dataCompilator[0]` should be incremented
- `a == b`: Nothing happens
- `a < b`: `dataCompilator[1]` should be incremented

And a ternary condition only addresses two cases. In your code it does the following:

- `a > b`: If true, `dataCompilator[0]` is incremented
- else: `dataCompilator[1]` is incremented

So you miss the equality case. To solve it only with ternaries, you could do the following (be aware that's only for the exercise, I would advocate against it in real code, as it makes the code difficult to read):

```
a > b ? dataCompilator[0] += 1 : (a < b ? dataCompilator[1] += 1 : null)
```

Comment: I think it would be much readable using just `if` `else if` cases...

Comment: @HaoWu  well yeah, that is likely why he advocates against it.

Comment: Thanks ! I will dig into this answer to find the ultimate logic and crack my ternary shell :)
Can't upvote since i do not have this power yet but take this message as one

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that, there are 3 states of comparison.

- Greater Than
- Less Than
- Equal

You are not checking for Equal, so for that scenario, by default you will go to else section. Hence output is `[1, 2]`

What you need is to add extra check for non-equal

```js
function compareTriplets(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2) {
  let dataCompilator = [0, 0]
  a0 > b0 ? dataCompilator[0] += 1 :  a0 < b0 ? dataCompilator[1] += 1 : 0;
  a1 > b1 ? dataCompilator[0] += 1 :  a1 < b1 ? dataCompilator[1] += 1 : 0;
  a2 > b2 ? dataCompilator[0] += 1 :  a2 < b2 ? dataCompilator[1] += 1 : 0;
  return dataCompilator;
}
console.log(compareTriplets(5, 6, 7, 3, 6, 10))
```

**Note:** Nested ternary operators are not good for readability and are sometimes considered bad practice. Its always better to use `if..else` ladder in such scenario

You can achieve same with loops to make things simple

```js
function compareTriplets(...args) {
  let alice = 0
  let bob = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length / 2; i++) {
    if (args[i] > args[args.length - i - 1])
      alice++
    else if (args[i] < args[args.length - i - 1])
      bob++
  }
  return [alice, bob];
}

console.log(compareTriplets(5, 6, 7, 3, 6, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks !! 
I really opened my mind on how i should improve my practices.
I am ashamed but i find the ternary way more readable, i should stick and focus to the else if statement.

Comment: @StefancicSamuel No need to be ashamed. For 1-2 level, ternary is readable but as you go deeper, it becomes tricky. **[For Example](https://jsfiddle.net/w0osb831/)** here `if...else` ladder is way better and its very easy to get lost.